# SQL DELETE with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-delete

There are 2 tables, `spawnlist` and `npc`, and I need to delete data from `spawnlsit`.
`npc_templateid = n.idTemplate` is the only thing that "connect" the tables.
I have tried this script but it doesn't work.

I have tried this:

```
DELETE s FROM spawnlist s
INNER JOIN npc n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate
WHERE (n.type = "monster");
```

Comment: Was more surprised because typically the L2 community keeps to its self.  Was a bit odd though reading the question and thinking "that looks like... hmm... it is!" :)

Comment: @Corbin I totally see what you mean. Interesting enough, I'm getting help on a L2 question to a work project.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Add `.*` to `s` in your first line.

Try:

```
DELETE s.* FROM spawnlist s
INNER JOIN npc n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate
WHERE (n.type = "monster");
```

Comment: Here is the error i got :

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'spawnlist
FROM db.root.spawnlist s
INNER JOIN db.root.npc n ON s.npc_t' at line 1
[Err] DELETE l2revo.root.spawnlist
FROM db.root.spawnlist s
INNER JOIN db.root.npc n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate
WHERE (n.type = "monster");
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: In your error it looks like your are using two different server names for `spawnlist`. I see `l2revo.root.spawnlist` and `db.root.spawnlist`.

Comment: i just make a mistake pasting it here, but the user name and db name are same , at my error.

Comment: Try adding `AS` for your aliases.

Comment: I just updated the code. Also, try removing the parens on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'spawnlist
FROM InnoDB.root.spawnlist AS s
INNER JOIN InnoDB.root.npc AS n 
ON' at line 1

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Try adding `.*` at the end of `spawnlist` on the first line. I updated the code above.

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'spawnlist.*
FROM InnoDB.root.spawnlist AS s
INNER JOIN InnoDB.root.npc AS n 
' at line 1

Comment: Actually. One more thing. Go back to your original query in your question and try adding `.*` to the `s` so: `DELETE s.*` and leave everything else the same.

Comment: i have changed what you said, there is no error,but the query dont want to finish, it is still in process right now, whats wrong ?

Comment: It could just be taking a long time to delete. Maybe there's a lot of data.

Comment: @DreamFactory It will. It won't work without the .*, which is what he had at first.

Comment: @GauravRamanan the s.* tells mysql what to DELETE, you don't want to delete rows from the JOINED table

Answer (score 14):

If the database is InnoDB then it might be a better idea to use foreign keys and cascade on delete, this would do what you want and also result in no redundant data being stored.

For this example however I don't think you need the first s:

```
DELETE s 
FROM spawnlist AS s 
INNER JOIN npc AS n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate 
WHERE n.type = "monster";
```

It might be a better idea to select the rows before deleting so you are sure your deleting what you wish to:

```
SELECT * FROM spawnlist
INNER JOIN npc ON spawnlist.npc_templateid = npc.idTemplate
WHERE npc.type = "monster";
```

You can also check the MySQL delete syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: This is the error i get :
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's
INNER JOIN npc n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate
WHERE n.type = "monste' at line 1
[Err] DELETE FROM spawnlist s
INNER JOIN npc n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate
WHERE n.type = "monster";
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: Changed, might be more successful now?

Comment: Error:

[Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'npc'
[Err] DELETE spawnlist FROM spawnlist, npc 
INNER JOIN npc 
WHERE spawnlist.npc_templateid = npc.idTemplate AND npc.type = "monster";
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: If you're just going to run it once, you could run the horribly inefficient: DELETE FROM spawnlist WHERE npc_templateid IN (SELECT idTemplate from npc WHERE type = "monster");

Comment: That's my last attempt, if your deleting from just one table on a join then I can't see why that won't work.

Comment: Idk, tested again and the error is the same:
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN npc ON spawnlist.npc_templateid = npc.idTemplate 
WHERE npc.type = '' at line 2

Comment: oh , :( its so hard to delete data from InnoDB  tables :(

Comment: Still no luck? Why don't you just set up a foreign key and when you delete from one table it removes from the other using cascade?

Comment: Hmm, is possible to make a code, that will delete the data from both tables ? cus i can restore 1 of them later. can you help pls?

Comment: You could create a view of a combination of both tables then delete from the view where `type = "monster";`

Comment: You shouldn't split an atomic query into two potentially-non-atomic queries. Here, you would need a transaction + you would need to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, unless, you won't write-lock the selected rows and another query from another session might DELETE some of them (not to mention that maybe 90% of devs will send the ids list to their client code, say Java or PHP, and resend them to the SQL with a utterly slow and ugly `WHERE id IN (...)` statement)

Answer (score 6):

if the database is InnoDB you dont need to do joins in deletion. only

```
DELETE FROM spawnlist WHERE spawnlist.type = "monster";
```

can be used to delete the all the records that linked with foreign keys in other tables, to do that you have to first linked your tables in design time.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST spawnlist (
  npc_templateid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY

)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST npc (
  idTemplate VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (idTemplate) REFERENCES spawnlist(npc_templateid) ON DELETE CASCADE

)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

if you uses MyISAM you can delete records joining like this

```
DELETE a,b
FROM `spawnlist` a
JOIN `npc` b
ON a.`npc_templateid` = b.`idTemplate`
WHERE a.`type` = 'monster';
```

in first line i have initialized the two temp tables for delet the record,
in second line i have assigned the existance table to both a and b but here i have linked both tables together with join keyword,
and i have matched the primary and foreign key for both tables that make link,
in last line i have filtered the record by field to delete.

Comment: `type` is actually in the other table, not in the `spawnlist` table, so join is necessary