# Delete rows when data missing 2 joins away

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I'm used to delete rows using joins in combination with "IS NULL", like 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610964/885872)

### Example:

Person A has number 1 of type 1. Person B has numer 2 of type 2, but also have number 1 of type 1.

### Query:

```
SELECT people.name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(phone_numbers.phone_number) AS "All number",
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(phone_numbers.type_id = 2, phone_numbers.phone_number, NULL)) AS "Type 2 Numbers" 
FROM people 
LEFT JOIN people_phones USING (people_id) 
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers USING (phone_number) 
GROUP BY people_id;
```

### Result:

```
+------+------------+----------------+
| name | All number | Type 2 Numbers |
+------+------------+----------------+
| A    | 1          | NULL           |
| B    | 1,2        | 2              |
+------+------------+----------------+
```

I want to remove all persons that don't have a type 2 number, in this case Person A.

First i tried the usal way (that works if its one join away)

### Tried:

```
DELETE people 
FROM people 
LEFT JOIN people_phones USING (people_id) 
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers 
  ON (phone_numbers.phone_number = people_phones.phone_number
      AND phone_numbers.type_id = 2) 
WHERE phone_numbers.phone_number IS NULL;
```

but that removes both Person 'A' and Person 'B' as 'B' has a number that isn't type 2.

How do i remove people that don't have a type 2 number?
(The real exemple have more joins, and more complex where parts, and 5 miljon rows in the tables.)

### SQL for recreateing my exemple data:

```
CREATE TABLE people (people_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, name TINYTEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (phone_number INT NOT NULL KEY, type_id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE people_phones (people_id INT NOT NULL, phone_number INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(people_id, phone_number))

INSERT INTO people VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B');
INSERT INTO phone_numbers VALUES (1, 1), (2,2);
INSERT INTO people_phones VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (2,2);
```

Comment: here is a fiddle link, that run the querys above, and both A and B gets deleted: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/218b23/2/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
DELETE p
FROM people AS p
WHERE p.people_id NOT IN (SELECT pp.people_id
                          FROM people_phones as pp
                          INNER JOIN phone_numbers as pn
                             ON pp.phone_number = pn.phone_number
                          WHERE pn.type_id = 2);
```

And another way:

```
DELETE p
FROM people AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM people_phones as pp
                 INNER JOIN phone_numbers as pn
                    ON pp.phone_number = pn.phone_number
                 WHERE pn.type_id = 2
                 AND pp.people_id = p.people_id);
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1181a4/1) with a demo of the second version (which is also the one that I recommend).

Comment: The 1st one using a function as reference, while the 2nd using the column, so the 2nd should be faster. Going to try the 2nd in my more complex situation.