# MySql Inner Join with Delete

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM `client_task`
INNER JOIN `project_task` 
        ON client_task.taskid=project_task.taskid
     WHERE projectid = '2'
```

I think you can see what i want to do, but i get following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `project_task` ON client_task.taskid=project_task.taskid ' at line 2

Cant figure out what´s the matter.
It´s MySql.

Comment: Which table are you trying to delete rows from? `client_task`, or both tables?  MySQL's syntax requires you to specify it like `DELETE client_task.* FROM client_task INNER JOIN...`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: thanks, solved the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL DELETE with INNER JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598791/sql-delete-with-inner-join)