# Delete with Join in Laravel 4 Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

Is there a way to make a Delete with Inner Join on Laravel 4 through a query builder?

I have this sample query [(sample query taken from this source.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598791/sql-delete-with-inner-join):

```
DELETE s.* FROM spawnlist s
INNER JOIN npc n ON s.npc_templateid = n.idTemplate
WHERE (n.type = "monster");
```

I've tried something like:

```
DB::table('spawnlist as s')
        ->join('npc as n', 's.npc_templateid', '=', 'n.idTemplate')
        ->where('n.type', 'monster')
        ->delete();
```

But the it seems that the join cannot be done here?

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way is to us laravel's event, it is more easier and clean.
you can perform same task like so:

```
DB::table('spawnlist')->delete();
```

then create a spawnlist event catch the deleting event and delete the other table like so:

```
Spawnlist::deleting( function ($sl) 
{
    DB::table('npc')->delete();
});
```

Comment: how about the where clause?

Comment: You can still add it before the delete method like so...    DB::table('spawnlist')->where('table.field', 'table.field')->delete();

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the DB facade to query and commit twice to the database?